# What is default mode for AEM filter.xml entry?

Tags: package, aem

In AEM, there is well known filter.xml file used to filter target paths of a package. Here is an example :

```
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/etc/map" mode="merge" />
</workspaceFilter>
```

In my current project, the developpers asked multiple times what is the default mode. I think it's `replace` but it's not clear in Jackrabbit / AEM documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes **replace** it a the default mode. The documentation says:

```
"replace : This is the normal behavior. Existing content is replaced
 completely by the imported content, i.e. is overridden or deleted
 accordingly.The normal mode"
```

https://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault/filter.html

The code is here (line 68):
https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-filevault/blob/e730ef9c999ac69b477675cd2671ff6ab5167d4d/vault-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/vault/fs/api/FilterSet.java

```
/**
 * import mode. defaults to {@link ImportMode#REPLACE}.
 */
@NotNull
private ImportMode mode = ImportMode.REPLACE;
```